# What is the support of posterior distribution?

Tags: probability, bayesian

The posterior distribution for a such parameter $\theta$ is proportional to $f(x|\theta)p(\theta)I(\theta)_{\theta \in A}$ where $A$ is the support for $\theta$ under the priori distribution and $I(\theta)_{(.)}$ is $1$ if $(.)$, its argument, holds and $0$ otherwise so we got:

$g(\theta|x) \propto f(x|\theta)p(\theta)I(\theta)_{\theta \in A} $

Now one suppose $\theta$ is from a paratameter's space $\Theta$ on $f$ as likelihood but I'm using a posterior which goes $\theta$ lying at $A$,not necessarily the same as $\Theta$, then the question is:

What is the theta posterior's support? Am I able to define another $J$ as indicator function and put the original parameters space as its argument and get the overlap between the both two arguments and so using another indicator? (the argument in $J$ and $I$). That's:

$g(\theta|x) \propto f(x|\theta)J(\theta)_{\theta \in \Theta}p(\theta)I(\theta)_{\theta \in A}$

$g(\theta|x) \propto f(x|\theta)p(\theta)K(\theta)_{\theta \in A \cap \Theta}$

Where $K$ is an another new indicator function, then would the new support be $A \cap \Theta$? Should I really need using indicator functions to get that?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to put the indicator functions there?

Comment: to get $\theta \in A \cap \Theta$